# Is possible to use Zend Form 2 with Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework2

I tried to exchange the Form folder of the new framework with the one in Zend Framework 1, but that didn't work.

I also tried to point ZF1 to the library the new Form 2.0 folder but I'm not able to get that to work either.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think it's impossible, since all components of ZF are loosely coupled. So all components can be used separately. However, you can not use ZF1 code to access the ZF2 form component, because it is completely rewritten. See also: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/overview.html

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use ZF2 components with ZF1 and it is relatively straight forward for the most part.

First of all you will need to clone zf2 into your library path, so cd to `library` and type:-

```
git clone https://github.com/zendframework/zf2.git Zf2
```

This will create a Zf2 folder under library.

We now need to tell the auto loader how to find zf2 files. in your bootstrap add the following:-

```
protected function _initZf2()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->pushAutoloader(new App_Loader_Autoloader_Zf2(), 'Zend');
}
```

Then we create the autoloader. I have a namespace called App_ which is included in application.ini with this line:-

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "App_"
```

and I created the autoloader in App/Loader/Autoloader/Zf2.php:-

```
class App_Loader_Autoloader_Zf2 implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        if(strstr($class, '\\')){
            $zf2Class = explode('\\', $class);
            $path = 'Zf2/library/' . implode('/', $zf2Class) . '.php';
            include_once $path;
        }
    }
}
```

Now zf1 knows where to find the zf2 classes when presented with the correct namespace. We can create a form, for example Application/Forms/Zf2.php :-

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Element\Text;

class Application_Form_Zf2 extends Form

{
    public function prepareElements()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Your name',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Now, in your controller, you can instantiate the zf2 form:-

```
$this->view->form = new Application_Form_Zf2();
$this->view->form->prepareElements();
```

As we are using a ZF1 view, we do not automatically have access to the [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html) that are used to render the ZF2 forms, so we have to explicitly instantiate them in the view as we need them:-

```
$form = $this->form;
$formHelper = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form();
$formText = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormText();
$formLabel = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel();
echo $formHelper->openTag($form);
echo $formLabel($form->get('name'));
echo $formText($form->get('name'));
echo $formHelper->closeTag($form);
```

This will output the following HTML:-

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Your name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

This method gives you a lot of control over the output of your forms and I would recommend hiding some of the code I have put in the phtml file above away in a ZF1 view helper.

Comment: I believe you wanted to say 'in ZF1' not 'in ZF2'?